# getting child id's from database dynamically?

Tags: php, mysql, function

I try to get the child id's of products dynamically.Below is my table structure.

```
parent|child
---------------------
44    | 35,6,47,5,50
---------------------
47    | 8,9
---------------------
50    | 12, 15
```

am going to pass only one parent id and get the child ids, and if anyone of child ids having again child, then i have to fetch that record also.example 44->35,6,47,5,50 in this 47 and 50 is having child ids, so my final output should be like this 44-> 35,6,47,8,9,5,50,12,15.

I tried below this,

```
$sql=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from chain_product where parent='44'"));
$parent=$sql['parent'];
$child=$sql['child'];
$ex=explode(",",$child);
$count=sizeof($ex);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
$list=add_child($ex[$i],$child);
$check=explode(",",$list);
$chck_count=sizeof($check);
if($chck_count>$count)
    {
            $exit=add_child($ex[$i],$list);
            print_r($exit);
    }
}

function add_child($main,$ch)
{
$find=mysql_query("select * from chain_product where parent='$main'");
$res=mysql_fetch_assoc($find);
if($res)
{
$replace=$main.",".$res['child'];
$alter=str_replace($main,$replace,$ch);
 echo $alter;
 }
}
```

but i get the result like this,

```
35,6,47,8,9,5,5035,6,47,5,50,12,15
```

but i need output should be like this..
    35,6,47,8,9,5,50,12,15.
can anyone help me to do this..

Comment: You just want to remove duplicates? [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) should do the trick... If you have a string, use `explode(',', $string)` to get an array first.

Comment: Never store multiple pieces of information in a single field. It will always cause you problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database structure isnt optimal for this, this would be better:

```
id | parent
1  | 0
2  | 1
3  | 1
4  | 2
5  | 2
```

This way you can do something **recursive**:

```
function getChilds($parent=0, $depth=0){
    // Select the items for the given $parent
    $query = $conn->mysqli_query("SELECT id WHERE parent=".$parent); // mysqli is better, but mysql will do fine
   // get the items by the parent giving as input:
    while($fetch = $query->fetch_assoc() ){
        echo str_repeat('-', $depth) . " ".$fetch['id'];        
        getChilds($fetch['id'], $depth+1); // Use id of this line to find its childs
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
getChilds(0); // And start it. The 0 is optional, I personaly prefer -1. Whatever rows your boat
```

This is called a tree structure and should give something like this:
1
- 2
- - 4
- - 5
- 3
In this example I use an echo for display purposes, you can return the values via an array, same principle

---

To answer a bit better, your current structure could support a similar method, but because you use strings, it will be allow slower and alot less flexible. You can see the difference in the code you are using, and the amount I just used. If you would remove the echo's and only return arrays, it will be even smaller :)